# Does SQL Server deferred name resolution work for functions?

Tags: sql-server, function

SQL Server has `Deferred Name Resolution` feature, read here for details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx

In that page, all it's talking is stored procedure so it seems `Deferred Name Resolution` only works for stored procedures and not for functions and I did some testing.

```
create or alter function f2(@i int)
returns table
as
    return (select fff from xxx)
go
```

Note the table `xxx` does not exist. When I execute the above `CREATE` statement, I got the following message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure f2, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 22]
>   Invalid object name 'xxx'.

It seems that SQL Server instantly found the non-existent table `xxx` and it proved `Deferred Name Resolution` doesn't work for `functions`. However when I slightly change it as follows:

```
create or alter function f1(@i int)
returns int
as 
begin
    declare @x int;
    select @x = fff from xxx;
    return @x
end
go
```

I can successfully execute it:

```
Commands completed successfully.
```

When executing the following statement:

```
select dbo.f1(3)
```

I got this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
>   Invalid object name 'xxx'.

So here it seems the resolution of the table `xxx` was deferred. The most important differences between these two cases is the return type. However I can't explain when `Deferred Name Resolution` will work for functions and when not. Can anyone help me to understand this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The return type here is relevant because you have two different types of functions. The function returning a table is an inline-table valued function and the second is a scalar function.

Comment: Whether or not DNR is available for functions, I'd strongly advocate against writing anything that relies upon it. IMO, it's more often a source of bugs (which have been transformed into runtime errors) than genuinely useful. At least with functions (unlike Stored Procs) you have the option of using `SCHEMABINDING` to move in the opposite direction.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7cc0e96-a847-42c8-ba4a-045904cabec7/does-sql-server-deferred-name-resolution-work-for-functions?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 7):

It feels like you were looking for understanding of why your particular example didn't work. Quassnoi's answer was correct but didn't offer a reason so I went searching and found this [MSDN Social answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/363ae51d-10db-4756-87c8-570aea41d105/what-happens-when-creating-a-function-?forum=transactsql) by Erland Sommarskog. The interesting part:

> However, it does not extend to views and inline-table functions. For
>   stored procedures and scalar functions, all SQL Server stores in the
>   database is the text of the module. But for views and inline-table
>   functions (which are parameterised view by another name) SQL Server
>   stores metadata about the columns etc. And that is not possible if the
>   table is missing.

Hope that helps with understanding why :-)

EDIT:

I did take some time to confirm Quassnoi's comment that `sys.columns` as well as several other tables did contain some metadata about the inline function so I am unsure if there is other metadata not written. However I thought I would add a few other notes I was able to find that may help explain in conjunction.

First a quote from [Wayne Sheffield's blog](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/):

> In the MTVF, you see only an operation called “Table Valued Function”. Everything that it is doing is essentially a black box – something is happening, and data gets returned. For MTVFs, SQL can’t “see” what it is that the MTVF is doing since it is being run in a separate context. What this means is that SQL has to run the MTVF as it is written, without being able to make any optimizations in the query plan to optimize it.

Then from the [SQL Server 2016 Exam 70-761 by Itzik Ben-Gan (Skill 3.1)](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-761-querying-data-with-transact-sql-9781509304332):

> The reason that it's called an *inline* function is because SQL Server inlines, or expands, the inner query definition, and constructs an internal query directly against the underlying tables.

So it seems the inline function essentially returns a query and is able to optimize it with the outer query, not allowing the black-box approach and thus not allowing deferred name resolution.

Comment: SQL Server stores column metadata for all table-valued functions, inline and multi-statement alike. It's trivial to verify this by creating the function from my post and querying `sys.columns`. This is possible for the multi-statement function even if the table is missing, because columns are explicitly defined in the function header, not the body.

Comment: @Quassnoi but it would not be possible to do this for an inline function unless the underlying query compiles successfully, as they dont have a definition in the header.

Comment: @Martin sure, it's just that "not possible" thing is quite misleading. SQL Server engineers could have just as easily dumped dnr support for the multi statement tvf and deduce the return type from the last SELECT statement in the block (which would require the block to compile at design time). It was a deliberate decision on their part not to do that but rather have the developers declare the return type explicitly in the header, most probably to keep the dnr around. It's not "impossible" for the views either: `CREATE VIEW (ID INT) AS BEGIN ... END` would be probably just as easy to implement

Comment: @Martin So what I was pointing out is that we have two types of tvf, but only one type each of views and scalar functions in SQL Server, and there is no other reason not to have two of either than a deliberate decision by the system architects.

Comment: yep - BTW I saw [on twitter recently](https://twitter.com/erinstellato/status/925868589684465665) that inline scalar functions should finally be coming soon

Comment: About time too!

Answer (score 5):

What you have in your first example is an inline function (it does not have `BEGIN/END`).

Inline functions can only be table-valued.

If you used a multi-statement table-valued function for you first example, like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION
        fn_test(@a INT)
RETURNS @ret TABLE
        (
        a INT
        )
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT
        INTO    @ret
        SELECT  a
        FROM    xxx
        RETURN
END
```

, it would compile alright and fail at runtime (if `xxx` would not exist), same as a stored procedure or a scalar UDF would.

So yes, DNR does work for all multi-statement functions (those with `BEGIN/END`), regardless of their return type.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi. do you know why it behaves like this?

Comment: @OgrishMan: because SQL Server developers have programmed it so. As to why did they (or rather Sybase engineers who had implemented deferred name resolution in the first place before SQL Server inherited it) decide it was a good idea, that I don't know.

Comment: @Quassnoi How would temp tables in procedures work without some form of DNR?

Comment: @smm: one way to do that would be to support persistent temporary tables like Oracle does (when the definition but not the data is stored in the schema and survives the disconnect and even the system restart) and only allow this kind of temp tables in stored procedures.